# sqlite database android

Tags: android, sqlite

I am currently developing an application with android and I need a database.

I created a database with SQLite Manager (firefox plugin).

how I can select items from the Database

I read the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) but I did not understand.

please help me.

Answer (score 3):

You first need to copy the database to the proper directory, such as in [this tutorial](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/).

It will also help you extend SQLiteOpenHelper which will get you a SQLiteDatabase object.

You can then use [SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(String, String[])](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5b%5d%29) to get a Cursor and start reading results.